# Extension to get warned when ::class is used in PHP but class is not used in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Is there any PHP extension for Visual Studio Code that can warn you in case you are doing ::class in PHP but the class is not `use`d on top of the file?

Let me show you a simple dummy example that proves my point:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Src\Users;

class ExampleClass
{
    protected string $anotherClass = AnotherExampleClass::class;
}
```

If you copy and paste this code on a PHP project in VSCode it won't highlight in red the `$anotherClass` declaration, even though `AnotherExampleClass` is not `use`d after the namespace line and is a class that is not within the same folder as `ExampleClass`.

This won't even work for me with PHP Intelephense and PHP IntelliSense extensions enabled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MehediDracula.php-namespace-resolver dose it solve your problem?

Comment: @MiladElyasi No, it doesn't. That extension helps you to add the namespace and I'm already using it. The problem that I explain is different because basically you are not warned that you should add the use for that class (in other words, you are not warned to use the extension you recommend).

Comment: You could try using PHP CodeSniffer for Visual Studio Code. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ikappas.phpcs I believe there is a custom rule named `PSR1.Classes.ClassDeclaration.MissingNamespace` that checks this

Comment: Hello @rperrone, that rule will only check if there is a missing namespace, not if there is a missing use of another class. Apparently it is not possible to check unless you use phpstan or other static analysis tools alike...

Answer (score 1):

if you want the class to be added automatically you can use spl_auto_register. Because sometimes it can be difficult to track the location of the files.
for ex.

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
global $dir;
if (file_exists($dir. $class . ".php")) {
    include $dir. $class . ".php";
} elseif (file_exists($class . ".php")) {
    include  $class . ".php";
}
```

});

```
You can check again with  is_file or file_exists .
```

Answer (score 0):

No syntax errors in this file. Namespace not mapped to single directory i.e. need analyze all project and vendor classes(try all registered auto-loaders).